# java how to update database value mysql query

Tags: java, mysql

Hello everyone im trying to make a simple update query in java but keep getting the same error over and over again. `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id=1' at line 1`
I dont understand what the problem is , can someone please explain why im getting this error? thanks everyone!

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
            String name = jTextField2.getText();
        int salary = Integer.parseInt(jTextField4.getText());

        String WorkPosition  = jTextField1.getText();
        Random rand = new Random();

        String Address = jTextField3.getText();
      int id =  Integer.parseInt(jTextField5.getText());
        Employee user = new Employee(id , name ,Address, salary, WorkPosition);





              try
    {
      // create a mysql database connection
      String myDriver = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
      String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("JDBC:mysql://localhost:3306/demo", "root", "root");

      // create a sql date object so we can use it in our INSERT statement
      Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
      java.sql.Date startDate = new java.sql.Date(calendar.getTime().getTime());

      // the mysql insert statement
       String query = "UPDATE Users SET name=?, salary=?, place=?, workposition=?, WHERE id=?";



      // create the mysql insert preparedstatement
      PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);

      preparedStmt.setString (1, user.name);
      preparedStmt.setInt (2, user.salary);
      preparedStmt.setString   (3,user.place);
  preparedStmt.setString (4,user.workposition);
     preparedStmt.setInt (5, user.id);
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record Updated!  ");

      // execute the preparedstatement
      preparedStmt.execute();

      conn.close();


    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.err.println("Got an exception!");
      System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the last ,

```
   String query = "UPDATE Users SET name=?, salary=?, place=?, workposition=? WHERE id=?";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
"UPDATE Users SET name=?, salary=?, place=?, workposition=?, WHERE id=?";
```

It looks like your syntax is wrong. Looking at mySQL Syntax guides this would be how to do an update

```
"UPDATE tableName SET columnName = {value|NULL|DEFAULT}, ... WHERE criteria"
```

It looks like you have an extra comma in your command. Yours should look something like this to work:

```
"UPDATE Users SET name=?, salary=?, place=?, workposition=? WHERE id=?";
```

If that works then try checking out [MySQL Examples for Beginners](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/MySQL_Beginner.html) for more help.